# C#, where is the App.config come from?

Tags: c#, configuration

I inherited a simple C# project without a App.config file. I need it now. How should I create one? manually or VS 2008 can do it for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it either way.  Right-click the project, select Add New Item, and then click on the Application Configuration item.

Simple.

Answer (score 4):

In VS 2008, right click the project, click Add -> new Item. Find 'Application Configuration File' under Templates. Click 'Add' and your done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either; manually create it in the root of the project, or just add it using New Item and choosing application config file.